# In C, does the order in which we allocate member's of a struct matter in terms of where the values are stored in memory

Tags: c, memory-management

Let's say I have a struct, foo.

```
struct foo {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};
```

If I allocate 12 bytes of memory for this struct
my understanding is that a block of memory will be allocated for the struct,
if I set the value of x first, then will the first 4 bytes of memory go to x?

How does the compiler know which are the locations of x, y, and z within the block for the struct

Comment: The compiler knows where the elements are because it decides where the elements are. The first element must be at the start of the allocated memory and the elements must remain in the order defined, aligned on appropriate boundaries (unless packed). Other than that, the compiler is free to pad the elements as it sees fit. Typically, it will pad the struct to make it a multiple of its minimal alignment requirement so you can make an array of them without alignment issues. Your example would probably become 16 bytes because 4 bytes of padding would be added for this purpose, assuming 4 byte int.

Comment: @SimonGoater This struct would not be padded to 16 bytes unless a higher alignment requirement is specified. The maximum alignment needs of any single member is 4 bytes, and so no padding is required to align the struct itself.

Comment: Oops, yes you're correct, my bad. Too used to using 64 bit values. If it were a uint64_t and a uint32_t then it would pad to 16 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it matters. The relative addresses of struct members is defined by the order in which they are declared. A special exception is bit-fields, whose packing and ordering is implementation-defined.

From the language standard current draft n3047 ([reference](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf))

> ### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers:
>
> ...
>
> 17. Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>     which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>     which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>     converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>     bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>     There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>     beginning.

In practical terms, the positions of its members are generally maintained as *offsets* from a base address. So, assuming "normal" conditions (no special alignment or padding rules) and a 4-byte `int`, then the offset (in bytes) of `x` is 0, `y` is 4, `z` is 8.

Notes:

1. You should *not* allocate "12 bytes" for a single `struct foo` object, but instead allocate `sizeof(struct foo)` bytes. You cannot guarantee that `sizeof(int)` is 4, nor that some other struct alignment requirements are in effect.
2. The size of `int` is implementation-defined. If you *require* a 32-bit signed integer, use `int32_t` from `<stdint.h>` instead.